# A windows script to batch convert rtf files to pdf

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have about 100 `.rtf` files, which I need to convert to `pdf` with the same name.

I use a cutepdf printer/plugin and print the file/save it as pdf.

Is there an automated way to do it or a command line method ?

Any help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Office 2007 or 2010 installed (which can export as PDF natively) you don't even have to go through the printer (although that should work too). There are plenty of examples on how to use PowerShell to automate conversion to PDF:

- [Powershell script for converting Word documents to PDF format](http://dougfernando.blogspot.de/2009/06/powershell-script-for-converting-word.html)
- [Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Convert Word Files to PDF Files?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/11/12/how-can-i-convert-word-files-to-pdf-files.aspx)

(Yes, they convert Word documents to PDF, but the process should be exactly the same for RTF, which has the same capabilities as the Word file format anyway).

Comment: Thank you very much. Is such a solution available for Office 2003 as well ?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could figure out how to use the COM interface to Office to print a document to a specific printer. But it might be that you cannot supply a file name automatically that way.